# phonegap jqm v1.1 rc1 fixed toolbars not working on android still

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-2.2-froyo

So I tried rebuilding my app using jquery mobile v1.1 rc1 since they claimed that the fixed tool bars work for android v2.2 now. I am also using phonegap 1.5 and jquery 1.7.1. Even tho the include files say its the lower versions, I have copy /pasted over with the most up to date versions.. to avoid changing the names of the files. However, the fixed tool bars still do not work and they scroll with the rest of the content. I have tried multiple things, including using data-fullscreen="true" on the pages with no success, I have included my html below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "fade";
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "fade";
});


</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- This reference to phonegap.js will allow for code hints as long as the current site has been configured as a mobile application. 
     To configure the site as a mobile application, go to Site -> Mobile Applications -> Configure Application Framework... -->
<script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body onLoad="bodyinit()"> 
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-fullscreen="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" class="ui-bar-b">
        <h1 id="headerid" style="font-size:large;">JenPad v1.toce</h1>


 <!-- <span style="float:left;margin-left:5px;margin-bottom:5px;">  <a href="#pagecreate" data-role="button" data-icon="add" data-iconpos="left">Note</a></span> <span style="float:right;margin-right:5px;"> 
  <!--<button data-icon="refresh" onClick="getAllItems()" data-iconpos="right">Refresh</button>-->
  <!--<span data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <button data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="left" onClick="getAllItems()">Refresh</button>
    <a data-role="button" data-icon="delete" href="#clearpage" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-iconpos="right">Clear</a>
  </span>
  </span>
    -->
  <div data-role="controlgroup" style="text-align:center;" data-type="horizontal">
    <a data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" href="#pagecreate">Note</a>
    <button data-icon="refresh" data-iconpos="left" onClick="getAllItems()">Refresh</button>
      <a data-role="button" data-icon="delete" href="#clearpage" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="none" data-iconpos="left">Clear</a>
    <button data-icon="info" data-iconpos="left" onClick="about()">About</button>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <div id="theLog"></div>
    <br>
     <p style="text-align:center;">Simply create a new "note" as a reminder for something worth remembering. Use the "Refresh" button to be sure you have the newest list of things to remember. Have Fun! </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>





<div data-role="page" id="pagecreate" data-fullscreen="true">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
    <h1 id="headerid" style="font-size:large;">Create Note</h1>
    <span style="float:left;margin-left:5px;margin-bottom:5px;>"<a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="left">Back</a></span>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content">

    <br>

     <textarea id="inputtext" rows="3" placeholder="Enter msg here.."></textarea><br>

     <div data-role="controlgroup">

       <button onClick="createItem()">Submit</button>

       <button type="reset" onClick="resetbtn()">Reset</button>

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="e" style="overflow:hidden;" id="clearpage">
  <div data-role="content"><h1 style="text-align:center;">Clear all notes?</h1>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div data-role="controlgroup" style="text-align:center;margin:auto 0;" data-type="horizontal">
    <button data-icon="check" data-iconpos="left" onClick="confirmclear()">Confirm</button>
    <button data-icon="back" data-iconpos="right" onClick="cancelclear()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I try the same html file in chrome it works with the fixed toolbar staying in place. I am using a LG optimus V with Android 2.2.1, any suggestions?

Comment: I have that same phone and I assure you they work as advertised. Your problem must be with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the jquery mobile docs and found that I had the following missing from my html file. after I included it , the fixed toolbars worked as expected:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```